# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle12c, stimulsoft

My Procedure is:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE MYPROC3
  (
    P_ID IN INTEGER,
    cc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
  OPEN cc FOR
  SELECT * FROM "createProjects" WHERE "id"=P_ID;
  END MYPROC3;
```

I am getting this error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROC3'

I am using oracle 12c

I'm going to use the stimulsoft I am getting this error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROC3'

In stimulsoft i have 
[stimulsoft error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtpyZ.png)

call stored procedure

```
DECLARE
 cc SYS_REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN
 PROC01(1, cc);
 dbms_output.put_line(cc);
 END;
```

Comment: can you please show the code on how you're calling the procedure? Because your problem lies in there.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso please see again

Comment: I believe (I can't test right now) you have to place the out in the calling of the procedure. ex: PROC01(1, out cc); Ps: I don't think you can directly output that cursor. Either you access each column name inside the cursor, or (again can't test it) I think Oracle has a package that allows that direct print from a cursor.